# problems with wordpress site after changing permalink structure

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

My wordpress site lies in a folder called `/entwurf/cob1` and since I wanted it to be shown by simply typing in `www.cob1.org` I changed the permalink to `cob1.org` and now nothing works. I tried changing the htacces to:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /entwurf/cob1/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /entwurf/cob1/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

but this doesnt seem to work either. I want my files who lie in the `entwurf/cob1/` folder to be shown when typing in the `cob1.org` website. 
Currently nothing is seen.

Comment: What was the original URL?  Wordpress hard codes url into the database

Comment: the original URL was www.cob1.org - and I had the wordpress files in a folder that could be found using the URL www.cob1.org/entwurf/cob1 
I made this draft folder in order to make changes without people knowing about. Today I checked the settings and changed the website URL and the permalink to www.cob1.org and I could not login anymore. Since then I am trying to change the htaccess in hope of any positive change..

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete `.htaccess`, log into your wordpress, and let wordpress to generate `.htaccess` for you. ( Options -> Permanent Links -> Save)
2. Check is it working? No?
3. Upload to your web site root phpinfo file (php file with a content of "`<?php phpinfo() ?>`"), run it via browser.
4. Check what Server API cell says -> Apache? If yes Check is there `mod_rewrite` enabled? No? Ask Support to enable it.

If its not a Apache, ask for a help of the person who setup your server.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the Worpdress admin panel go to 
Setting > General 
and make sure the Wordpress URL and Site URL are correct. They should be your new address. Change those and save it if you want to rewrite all the old URLS in the database.

If you don't have access to the WP admin panel try using this to manually make the changes to your database.

https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Answer (score 0):

Delete .htaccess and regenerate it. Else use the following:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /entwurf/cob1/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Secondly, what you are trying to achieve has to be done in two steps.

1) In Settings > General, change the wordpress url in both fields to www.cob1.org
2) In your apache config, set www.cob1.org to point to /entwurf/cob1/

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "complete-absolute-path-to/entwurf/cob1/"
    ServerName cob1.org
    ServerAlias www.cob1.org
</VirtualHost>
```

3) Verify that .htaccess is being read. This takes a little bit of experimentation. Eg. I'd place some random text in .htaccess to force a server error on purpose. If I see the error, that means that the .htaccess file is being read. If it's not being read, make sure "AllowOverride All" is set in the apache config. .htaccess files are only read by apache (and apache family servers.)
Restart apache. You're done.

Comment: The problem is I cannot log into wordpress anymore. So I can't access my admin panel or check the settings. And I also already tried with the:

    RewriteRule . index.php [L]

solution. It seems like nothing works. I am absolutely clueless.. :-/